# Is there a way to get the user inputs from floating filters in AG-grid?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, export-to-excel, ag-grid-react

I have a react application with an ag-grid data table. I have created a custom Excel Export for the Ag-grid data since we don’t want to invest in the Enterprise version yet. The only problem with this is when floating filters are used the entire data gets exported to the excel sheet even after the filter is applied. I was wondering if there is a way to read the user input from the floating filters and filter the output data accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Use `gridApi.getFilterModel()` method. See [docs on Filter API](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/filter-api/).